# Extract only digits between two specific tags using regex

Tags: regex, tags

Can somebody help me to construct this regex please.

I have the following string:

`<Guid>Abc1234</Guid>`

I need to extract only the digits from it.
So far I managed to get the whole text: Abc1234 with

`(?<=<Guid>)(.*?)(?=<\/Guid>)`

But i need a regex to extract only the digits: 1234.

Thank you.

Comment: Are the digits always at the end of can they be anywhere in the string? Also, which language? Why not just use an XML parser?

Comment: The digits are always at the end of the string. I want to filter the digits in order to replace them with Notepad++. But i need to replace only the digits.

Comment: Why not just use `\d+(?=<\/Guid>)`?

Comment: Nice one. Thank you ! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specified the numbers are **always** at the end of the string inside the tag (in the comments below your question), you don't need to ensure the opening tag is there. Just match before the closing tag: You're not validating, but extracting.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Rfd59s/1)

```
\d+(?=<\/Guid>)
```

If you **must** ensure the start is there, you may use `<Guid>.*?\K\d+(?=<\/Guid>)` instead. `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match.